# iOS MagicalRecord grouping and sorting for tableview. How do they work, exactly?

Tags: ios, uitableview, magicalrecord

I've got a tiny test app using Core Data via MagicalRecord for the purpose of learning how to group activities by categories. I want to display the data in a grouped tableview with the names of all the activities sharing a common category grouped together under categories. Accordingly, I've got an entity called ListActivity, which has two attributes, "name" and "category," both strings.

Currently, I'm using:

```
frc = [ListActivity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:@"category" withPredicate:nil sortedBy:@"name" ascending:YES];
```

To my mind (being unable to find clear documentation to the contrary) this seems to fit the bill, but not so.

**In the following screenshot, I've entered an activity named "a" under category "K."**

[image]

**Fine so far.
Next, I enter the activity named "k" under category "A."**

[image]

While the Categories appear to arrange themselves properly as section titles via:

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[frc sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo name];

}
```

the activities themselves float right though and out of the group (category) to which they are assigned, yet remain alphabetized.

I've been all over the web, all over SO, Github, etc., and can't seem to find anything that explains the grouping and sorting behavior of MR's fetchAll and findAll methods, except in general terms. Can someone with MagicalRecord experience please help, or point me to documentation or a tutorial?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grouping helper in MagicalRecord is merely a convenience method on top of the NSFetchResultsController. Any documentation relating to that class directly applies to this method. The only extra caveat with the MagicalRecord methods is that they will perform the fetch for you. Also, you may need to refetch (or use MR_performFetch) the data to get  updates in your data reflected in the data you have in memory.

That said, your grouping depends on a couple of things in the data model. The category attribute must be present in the entity data which you're grouping. It looks like you have this step. If you want to respond to changes in the data, you'll need to implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate protocol and set a delegate on the NSFRC that is returned from the MR_fetchAll* methods.

I suggest looking at the NSFetchedResultsController examples, as those directly apply to all uses of the MagicalRecord fetching helpers.

Comment: Ok, @casa, thanks. I was hoping to avoid the deep weeds, but I certainly can't ask for a higher authority on MagicalRecord. I've been reading Apple's docs, and will continue.